# Solr and Ajax autocomplete with remote datasource

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, solr, datasource

I'm using JSP in implementing auto-complete using Solr, I'm using the following code in order to retrieve a list of terms:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.addTermsField("name_auto");
query.setTerms(true); 
query.setTermsPrefix(TEXTFIELD VALUE);

...
```

I've to retrieve the list of terms based on the value of the text field (the Prefix)(ex:"k"), also, I've to update this list for each key press.

I followed this link: 
http://www.mattweber.org/2009/05/02/solr-autosuggest-with-termscomponent-and-jquery/

and I'm using those JQuery files: (it the same founded in Google library)
http://jquery.com/

cause I tried this code but the problem is how can I write the URL so I can do a remote data source to my auto-Complete???

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868985/javascript-jsp

Comment: Hi javanna, I Know that that JSP work on server side and the JP on client, I just want to know if there any other solution to know the value of the textfield to use it as prefix. thankx

Comment: I still understand your question to be accessing JS content within the same JSP, which can not be done. Please feel free to edit the post with more details, but my duplicate comment still stands.

Comment: OK thanks, I change my question totally hope my question will be clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Thank u all, I fix my prblem using JQueryUI files and tutorials, this my code:

```
$(function() {
$( MYTEXTFIELDNAME ).autocomplete({
   source: function( request, response ) {
     $.ajax({
           url: 'http://localhost:8080/solr/terms?terms=true&terms.fl=MYAUTOFIELD&terms.prefix=' 
                +request.term+'&wt=json',
     dataType: "json",
     data: {
       style: "full",
       maxRows: 5,
       name_startsWith: request.term
      },

      success: function( data ) {
     response( $.map( data.terms.MYAUTOFIELD, function( item ) {
      return {
        label: item,
        value: item,
             }
    }));
    }
         });
     },
      minLength: 1,
....
```

the remaining code is as described in http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

thanks again.